# Insert new row in a Google Sheet and copy a pre-formatted row into it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my second Google Apps Script and I'm stuck so would appreciate some assistance.

**Requirement:**
I would like to automate the process of adding a new row into a Google Sheet.

The script will insert a new row after a selected row and then copy a pre-formatted row (which is hidden) into the new row.

**Progress to-date:**
The script below inserts the new row okay, but then copies the pre-formatted row into the previously selected row rather than the new one.

What needs to be changed to get the script to copy into the new row?

```
function onOpen(e) {
var menu = [{name: "Row", functionName: "addRow"}]
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Add", menu);
}

function addRow() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), Active = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange("PreFormattedRow");
sheet.insertRowAfter(Active);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getActiveCell());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try incrementing the row of the active cell with 1. That should get you the newly inserted row.

```
function addRow() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    row = sheet.getActiveCell()
        .getRow(),
    rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange("PreFormattedRow");
sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much JPV. It's easy when you know how!

Answer (score 0):

your all google script is correct. only you have to add below one line to get
previously selected row format into new added raw one.

```
rangeToCopy.copyFormatToRange(sheet.getActiveCell());
```

and for removing row format

```
rangeToCopy.copyValuesToRange(sheet.getActiveCell());
```