# How to copy row of data from 1 tab to another without overriding the data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am pulling some tickets from Jira to a sheet and then perform some calculations on each of the rows.

Separately, I am pulling any new tickets on another tab to see if any new tickets need calculation. So my current setup looks like this:

```
Tab1 "Calc" sheet

Issue 113, Description, Priority, Score
Issue 112, Description, Priority, Score
```

In the same sheet I have a separate tab to pull any new tickets from Jira

```
Tab2 "Pull" sheet

Issue 115, Description, Priority
Issue 114, Description, Priority
Issue 113, Description, Priority
Issue 112, Description, Priority
```

Now because I have two new tickets 114 & 115, I need to copy these rows over into Tab1, without overriding the existing data.

How can I do this?

Comment: Go to Tab1. Cell `Issue 113`. Right click, insert row. You need to do it  twice(I think!). Then paste.

Comment: @Madhurjya the idea is to automate this based on a Vlookup or something like that. Manual copy paste is not going to be feasable. I couldn't figure a way to automatically copy the items from Tab2 onto Tab1 based on a formula

Comment: Is Tab2 loaded automatically as well? @Nant

Comment: Maybe you can use Apps script for that. or maybe a macro.

Comment: @Nant take a look on this answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24362318/6868879 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41621713/6868879, does it help you?

Comment: Is the "Score" in the Tab1 Calc sheet calculated automatically, or entered?  If automatic, you could reimport all records from the Tab2 Pull sheet using ImportRange, and calculate scores for all records.  Perhaps if you provide a sample sheet, we can better understand your data situation?